# Duinotech ATTINY85 Pinout

Tags: pins, digispark

I'm sure this is a super nooby question but,

what is the pinout of the Digispark ATTINY85 Development Board

The board looks like this:
[image: Board]

Now the reason why I'm asking this question, when I do `digitalWrite(1, HIGH);`, the test light will come on. My question is then, what is the virtual number for PB1 (P1 in photo).

Also, does that arduino output + or -?

Any help is appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/alaspuresujay/use-an-attiny85-with-arduino-ide-07740c) seems to show an obvious pinout with an LED connected to p1 (digital pin 1).
With "virtual number" I guess you mean the Arduino pin nr. As your code shows you, it's Arduino pin 1.

Comment: when I do digitalWrite(1, HIGH);, the test light will come on.

Comment: nvm, got what you mean now.